# Does $f(x,y,x)= \frac{|x|+|y|+|z|}{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2 + z^2}}$ have a limit for $f(x,y,z) \to(0,0,0)$

Tags: analysis, limits

$f: R^3\setminus\{(0,0,0)\} \to R$

I'm new to multivariable limits and I'm kind of stuck here

Comment: Try going to $0$ while following two different straight lines.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Given $k>0$, along the line defined by $y=kx$ and $z=0$, you have
$$f(x,y,z) = f(x,kx,0) = \frac{(1+k)|x|}{\sqrt{(1+k^2)x^2}} = \frac{1+k}{\sqrt{1+k^2}}$$